# Prevent Segue Transition in Login Swift/Parse

Tags: ios, swift

I have a login view controller where it should prevent the user from transition to the next view controller via a segue called "toMasterTab". I think the logic might be wrong - if the user entered the correct credentials and is not empty, it transitions fine, but if the user entered no credentials (nil) and entered the wrong credentials, then it should prevent the segue. So far, I can only get the UIAlertView to pop up, but other than that, I can't solve this...

```
    @IBAction func loginButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    let RedPlanetUser = RPUsername.text
    let RedPlanetUserPassword = RPUserPassword.text

    PFUser.logInWithUsernameInBackground(RedPlanetUser!, password: RedPlanetUserPassword!) {
        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if user != nil {
            // Do stuff after successful login
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toMasterTab", sender: self)
            print("User logged in successfully")
        } else {
            // Login failed
            print("User log in failed")
            // Present alert
            var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Login Failed",
                message: "The username and password do not match.",
                delegate: self,
                cancelButtonTitle: "Try Again")
                alert.show()

            func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier(identifier: String!, object: AnyObject) -> Bool {
                let identifier = "toMasterTab"
                    // prevent segue
                return false
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you know a valid username and password? What happens when you put that in?

Comment: Then segue would go straight to the app's main UI

Comment: How is that different from what you want?

Comment: Have look at this and see if it helps. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90062/checking-two-text-field-for-match-and-checking-for-null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you should be overriding the

```
override func shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier
```

The problem was that the segue was connected to the button, so it automatically performed the segue even when the conditions were NOT met. I connected the segue from VC1 to VC2 and used the following code when the conditions were met, and didn't call the segue when the conditions were erroneous:

```
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("toMasterTab", sender: self)
```

Comment: Maybe you could try simply implementing the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier function and putting the login login in there. Check if the identifier matches the segue you're looking for first, then if the user credentials work, return true, otherwise display the popup and return false to indicate that the segue should be prevented.

Comment: Ok I'll try that. Also, the segue type in the storyboard should be custom right, not show?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with having show as segue type. Using the shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier is not restricted to custom segues, its used as validation for any segue to determine wether or not it should be performed.

Comment: WOW, I'm a total idiot/moron. I don't deserve to code... BUT I found out that the problem was that I connected the login button to the segue, not the VC. NOW it works. Thanks a ton!